# Is it possible to get global optimal solution for TSP using or-tools?

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I solve the asymmetric traveling salesman problem with or-tools using this example https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp
or-tools returns some solution, but I need the best solution. Can you please tell how to customize or-tools to return a globally optimal solution for TSP?

I could not find this information on the or-tools forum.
Of course I can set some very big number in search parameter, for example search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 100000
and wait a lot of time, but in any case I will know nothing about optimality of the solution

Answer (score 1):

the routing library is an approximate solver.
It is not designed to prove optimality.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please recommend some solver for the asymmetric traveling salesman problem that can return a globally optimal solution?

Comment: I do not know. Concorde is symmetric. This is a hard problem.